# WHy is awesome_print gem showing <br /> in rspec output

Tags: awesomeprint

I'm getting this output from ap, in my rspec test

```
"line1"<br />
"line2"<br />
"city"<br />
"state"<br />
"zip"<br />
"country"<br />
```

It is not because of the :html option, because when that's on it looks like:

```
&lt;pre>&lt;kbd style="color:brown">&quot;line1&quot;&lt;/kbd>&lt;/pre><br />
&lt;pre>&lt;kbd style="color:brown">&quot;line2&quot;&lt;/kbd>&lt;/pre><br />
&lt;pre>&lt;kbd style="color:brown">&quot;city&quot;&lt;/kbd>&lt;/pre><br />
&lt;pre>&lt;kbd style="color:brown">&quot;state&quot;&lt;/kbd>&lt;/pre><br />
&lt;pre>&lt;kbd style="color:brown">&quot;zip&quot;&lt;/kbd>&lt;/pre><br />
&lt;pre>&lt;kbd style="color:brown">&quot;country&quot;&lt;/kbd>&lt;/pre><br />
```

Comment: In what are you rendering it ? A webpage I suppose, but if not try using "\n".

Comment: In rspec, in unit tests...